# Learning Blender from basic to experts

Tags: modeling

I want to learn blender from basic to expert all options. Are there DVD available to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: Use it to learn it... Also "Google Blender tutorials". Basic ones like https://vimeo.com/channels/blendervideotutorials/videos/sort:alphabetical/format:thumbnail and somewhat self serving but great http://www.blenderguru.com/ and more

Answer (score 5):

I recommend blenderguru.com like one of the above comments mentions, but for me just playing around with the program and getting familiar before jumping in to tutorials helps.